# Deedle throws System.OutOfMemoryException when reading large csv file

Tags: .net, csv, f#, deedle

I was very excited to find Deedle few days ago which seems to be great tool for data analysis in NET world. However some of my data are in csv files and Frame.ReadCsv method throws System.OutOfMemoryException for files about 200MB or larger. I played with Frame.ReadCsv parameters with no success. I can pre-process data in some cases before loading into dataframe, but it would be nice to be able handle them directly in Deedle. R has no issues loading these files into dataframe.
Any recommendation?

I come across BigDeedle example, but it does not look trivial and I wonder if there are simpler solution which does not require additional code.
Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Mitch, my client does not use R and it would be overkill for my task.

Comment: I'm not sure how that it is relevant. R is free. If it's you that;s doing the data analysis why would it matter what you use?

Comment: It is about approved tools company uses. Deedle falls into .net category which is approved. It also could be integrated into .net apps.

Comment: I tried using FileStream, but got the same OutOfMemory error.

Comment: This is something we'd like to address - can you please open an issue on GitHub: https://github.com/BlueMountainCapital/Deedle/issues/new with more details about the file you're loading? (A small sample with some fake values would be idea...)

Comment: check your FSI settings for 64 bit with  'let is64Bit = System.IntPtr.Size = 8'

Comment: Tomas - issue has been opened https://github.com/BlueMountainCapital/Deedle/issues/332

Comment: Functional_S - I used 32bit FSI, after switching to 64bit (Tools->Options->F# Tools->F# Interactive) I have no issues loading much larger files (ex: 1GB csv file with about 15MM rows). Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your FSI settings for 64 bit with

```
let is64Bit = (System.IntPtr.Size = 8)
```

And configure Visual-Studio to switch FSI to 64 bit, here:

```
Tools -> Options -> F# Tools -> F# Interactive
```

Comment: I had same issue some time ago and did exactly this. I think this should solve it also in this case.